# Install-SPSolution : This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web appli cation and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that deploys about 12 web parts. They have all been created through Visual Studio 2010 and are being deployed to SharePoint 2010.

I am getting the following error when running `Install-SPSolution` for one of my web parts:

```
Install-SPSolution : This solution contains no resources scoped for a Web application and cannot be deployed to a particular Web application.
```

Can someone help me debug this? Every other `Install-SPSolution` command uses `-AllWebApplications`, and I do not want to specify the web application directly using `-URL`. Here is the command that is breaking (this is the same command used to successfully deploy all 11 other web parts):

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity PortalSelector.wsp -AllWebApplications -GACDeployment
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a bit late to the party but...

The error suggests that the solution that you are trying to install does not need to update the web.config file of a web application in order for the features and resources contained within the solution to be used or activated on it.

The types of changes that solutions often need to apply to web.config files are things like safe control entries, HTTP modules, assembly binding redirect and such.

My guess would be that all you need to do is omit the `-AllWebApplications` switch from your command:

```
Install-SPSolution –Identity PortalSelector.wsp -GACDeployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in your feature.xml file - it should have an XML attribute `Scope` that I am guessing contains the value `Site` - try changing it to `Web`.

Any chance you could try the same command using STSADM instead? It sometimes gives more helpful output. Try something like:

```
STSADM -o addsolution -filename PortalSelector.wsp
STSADM -o deploysolution -name PortalSelector -immediate
STSADM -execadmsvcjobs
```